# How to use a string value as param in function using string pointer variable as input parameter

Tags: c++, string, pointers

This is the function I am coding now-

```
insertobjectnames(std::string clsname, std::string objname)
```

Now within the above function I have to invoke another function that takes as input the same parameters as above 2, but first one as string and second one as string pointer variable

The declaration for the second function is given below-

```
 int  analyse(const std::string key, std::string * key2)
```

How do I use the `objname` parameter from the first function to invoke the second function above? The second function (within itself) extracts the value of `key2` from the parameters and then uses them as per requirements.

Comment: First, there's usually no good reason for `analyse` to expect a pointer for `key2`. It should take a reference (or a const reference, if it's not going to modify key2). Similarly, using `const reference` parameters instead of passing strings by value is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` operator in C++: its the address-of operator: basically a variable to pointer converter! Ex:

```
int a = 0;
int *pointertoa = &a;
//So
std::string s;
std::string *ps = &s; //Extracting the "key" ps is a pointer to s
analyse(key, &objname); //should be the right way to pass the parameter as a pointer
```

Comment: @awesomeyi- AFAIK SO asks for answers- hence please post the answer otherwise I cannot accept your hint as the answer.(And I have understood what you mean- thanks a  lot :) )